# Two classes with a same name in PlantUML class diagram

Tags: class-diagram, plantuml

Dear community members and PlantUml practitioners,

I would like to have two classes with the same name such as:

- Test << stereotype >>
- Test

and I would like to make relation between those two classes. 
Is it possible to make alias for classes in class diagram so I can make distinction between the classes thus those will be represented as two different elements.

Any idea?

Comment: hm I dont know PlantUml but you can not have classes with same name because if you will generate source code it end with error. But you can have same classes in different namespaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With plantuml you can alias a display name using "as."  For class diagrams it looks Like this:

```
@startuml
class "Test" as t1
class "Test" as t2
t1 -> t2
@enduml
```

[image: As rendered by the online planuml server at http://www.plantuml.com]

Comment: see also: http://forum.plantuml.net/8111/two-classes-with-a-same-name-in-class-diagram

Comment: Thanks I lot John and I apologize for the lag of my response. I was thinking that I tried the aliases in this context but it was obvious that I didn't.

Thanks a lot for the provided solution to my problem.